# Как перевести формат Object в Time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

В DataFrame два столбца:

```
Время        Время с 
10:54:55     10:30:00
11:49:15     11:30:00
17:42:45     17:30:00
18:55:46     18:30:00
20:04:01     20:00:00
```

Тип данных обоих столбцов `Object`.

Как получить разность двух столбцов?

```
df['Время'] - df ['Время с']
```

Answer (score 2):

чтобы получить разность дат/времен надо привести оба столбца к типу `datetime`:

```
In [119]: pd.to_datetime(df['Время']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Время с'])
Out[119]:
0   00:24:55
1   00:19:15
2   00:12:45
3   00:25:46
4   00:04:01
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```